# Cant connect to xapi using PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl

I try to login to xtb api ( xtrade brokers api demo) and  I can't do it
My code below:

```
$headers = (object) [
        'command' => 'login',
            'arguments' => (object) [
            'userId' => 'myuserID',
            'password' => 'myPassword'
                                    ]
                    ];

$object = json_encode($headers);
    
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'xapi.xtb.com');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PORT, 5124);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $object);
$ret = curl_exec($curl);
$error = curl_error($curl);
$info = curl_getinfo($curl);
print_r($ret);
echo "<br><br>";
print_r($error);
echo "<br><br>";
print_r($info);
echo "<br><br>";
```

My output response

> Failed to connect to xapi.xtb.com port 5124 after 81 ms: Connection
> refused

Comment: You are sending data in the request's header, should it be in the data? try changing `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`

Comment: Tried and got same response :/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
        $host = "xapi.xtb.com";
        $port = 5124;
        $user = '10000';
        $pass = 'secret_password';

        $ssl_context = stream_context_create(array(
                'ssl' => array(
                        'verify_peer' => false,
                        'verify_peer_name' => false,
                        'allow_self_signed' => true
                )
        ));

        $socket = stream_socket_client("ssl://$host:$port", $errno, $errstr, 5, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ssl_context);

        if (!$socket) {
                die("Not connect: ($errno) $errstr");
        }

        $cmd = json_encode(array (
          'command' => 'login',
          'arguments' => array (
            'userId' => $user,
            'password' => $pass,
          ),
        ) );



        fwrite($socket, $cmd);

        $result = fread($socket, 1024);
        echo "Result from server: $result";

        fclose($socket);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).